# Trying to install numpy 1.7

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I am currently using Python 2.7 and Numpy 1.6.2. I want to use the [`numpy.polyfit()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html) function with the weights parameter. However, it seems that the weights parameter is not available in numpy 1.6.2. The Sourceforge [download link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/) shows 1.6.2 as being the latest version. I have found the updated [`polynomial.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L394) file which includes the weights parameter for the `polyfit()` function. I simply replaced my current `polynomial.py` with the updated one on the website. However, when I try to run my Python program, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\first.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 52, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    import polynomial
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\polynomial\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from polynomial import Polynomial
ImportError: cannot import name Polynomial
```

`first.py` is simply the file with all my code I'm trying to run

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to simply get the newest version of Numpy (1.7?) ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the edits senderle! I will format my questions as such from now on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two files called `polynomial.py` in NumPy; `lib/polynomial.py` and `polynomial/polynomial.py`.  You've replaced the wrong one.

I'm not aware of any development builds of 1.7.x for Windows; if you're comfortable with building packages yourself then you can download the source using git and build it per instructions from https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_RELEASE.rst.txt and linked resources.